# how to  create  ipa file for iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am building an app and making an ipa file but is not ceated .I have xcode version 3.2.6 and followed the steps  necessary to make the ipa file.But no hope . i  and archived the application and opened it in organizer then distribute it but it does not show any alert that ipa file is creating.

Comment: Please make this into a question and give more specifics

Comment: @Otium i have given more detail you can see

Comment: While creating build,do you select iOS device in scheme? try to clean,build and then archive.

Comment: @Sarah yes i am selecting device but my xcode version is 3.2.6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Steps to make .ipa file

1. First Clean the project(Command+Shift+K)
2. Build the project(cammand + B) and/or Run the project(Command + R) (Make Sure to make Release build)
3. Under project Navigator, go to Product/ProjectName.app
4. Right click on ProjectName.app file and select "show in Finder "
5. Copy the ProjectName.app file
6. Create a new folder and paste the ProjectName.app file
7. Compress the  folder and name it ProjectName.ipa and remove the .zip extension.
8. A pop will come to ask you for using .ipa extension, select "use .ipa" and press Enter.

Now your .ipa file is ready to use, You can drag and drop it to the iTunes and use it in a Testing device by syncing the device with the particular iTunes.

Comment: Are you making distribution build or release build?

Comment: distribution build for adhoc only testing

Comment: I had this problem when i was creating distribution build, but when i run the .ipa file second time it was running perfectly.

Comment: There was a problem in Distribution profile and we created another distribution profile and it was running perfactly

Comment: mean i have created a new provisioning profile with Device ID and may i also create another distribution profile and also download it

Comment: i have download both distribution and provisioning profiles both for to run this on device

Comment: @KhushbuPatel Hi, Khushbu, i tried your way, but it doesn't work for me, in my app under project navigator the .app file does not have show in finder option enabled. In my xcode i have installed profiles many time every time it say invalid profile, but in other system same created profile works fine. What could be wrong here, Can you please guide for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder and drag, drop .app and provisionaing profile into that folder. Compress it. Replace .zip extension with .ipa. Thats it.

Comment: while creating profile you have to give description as "com.yourcompanyname.appname". You need to set the same value for Bundle Identifier in your info plist file. Then generate build.